# Gráficos de dispersão fixando uma variável resposta

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suponha que eu tenho interesse no conjunto de dados `iris`, já presente na memória do `R`:

```
head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Eu gostaria de fixar uma das colunas deste conjunto de dados como minha variável resposta e plotar os gráficos de dispersão entre esta coluna e as demais presente em `iris`. Por exemplo, se eu fixar `Petal.Length`, eu gostaria de ver os seguintes gráficos de dispersão feitos através do pacote `ggplot2`:

- `Petal.Length` e `Sepal.Length`
- `Petal.Length` e `Sepal.Width`
- `Petal.Length` e `Petal.Width`

Não é necessário fazer distinção entre as diferentes `Species`. Sei como fazer isto manualmente, da seguinte forma:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

g1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length , y = Petal.Length)) +
geom_point()
g2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width , y = Petal.Length)) +
geom_point()
g3 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width , y = Petal.Length)) +
geom_point()

grid.arrange(g1, g2, g3, ncol=3)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto, eu gostaria de uma maneira automatizada de fazer isto, principalmente para os casos em que vão haver mais de 3 variáveis preditoras em meu conjunto de dados.

Como proceder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução é primeiro colocar seu `data.frame` no formato `long`, e depois usar no `ggplot2` diretamente:

```
# carrega pacotes
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

# coloca dados no formato long
iris_long <- melt(iris, id = c("Petal.Length", "Species"))

# plot com ggplot2
ggplot(iris_long, aes(y = Petal.Length, x = value)) + 
  geom_point() + facet_wrap(~variable)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por default, o `facet_wrap` usa a mesma escala para todas as facetas, mas você pode alterar isso conforme gosto. Por exemplo, facetas com escalas livres:

```
ggplot(iris_long, aes(y = Petal.Length, x = value)) + 
  geom_point() + facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Minha abordagem foi pegar o nome das variáveis e passá-las no `ggplot` como texto dentro dos colchetes duplos `[[`.

```
colunas <- names(iris)
resposta <- colunas[1] # escolhe variável resposta
colunas <- colunas[-c(1,5)] # remove resposta e as espécies

graficos <- lapply(colunas, function(explicativa, df, resposta) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x = df[[explicativa]] , y = df[[resposta]])) +
    geom_point()
}, df = iris, resposta = resposta)

grid.arrange(grobs = graficos, ncol = length(graficos))
```

**Editado**

Outra solução possível é construir o código como um texto e passar ele em `parse()` e depois `eval()`. É importante que o argumento passado para `eval()` seja nomeado `text`. Assim:

```
graficos <- lapply(colunas, function(explicativa, df, resposta) {
  codigo <- sprintf("ggplot(df, aes(x = %s, y = %s)) + geom_point()",
                    explicativa, resposta)    
  eval(parse(text = codigo))
}, df = iris, resposta = resposta)
```

Comment: Resposta simples e elegante. Excelente.